# R: Transform large list into data frame and keeping null values

Tags: r, list, join, null, data-manipulation

I have an object called 'data' containing information about real estate property:

```
> class(data)
[1] "data.frame"`
> dim(data)
[1] 351  13
```

Whitin its columns, there is one called 'addresses'

```
> class(data$addresses)
[1] "character"
```

I used the function `cartociudad_geocode()` to get the maximum amount of addresses geolocalized:

```
geo_info<-sapply(data$addresses, cartociudad_geocode, on.error="warn")
```

Which resulted in a large list of 351 elements,  with geographical info of all of the strings of addressed that DID get geolocalized. The ones that DIDN'T appear as **NULL**:

```
> dput(head(geo_info, 4))
list(`Valencia, Avenida Nº S.n. Planta 1 Castellon De La Plana/Castello De La Plana` = structure(list(
    id = "2061380170886", province = "Badajoz", comunidadAutonoma = "Extremadura", 
    muni = "Valdetorres", type = "portal", address = "PLAN PARCIAL Nº 1", 
    postalCode = "06474", poblacion = "Valdetorres", geom = "POINT(-6.07339711488708 38.91670317033)", 
    tip_via = "BARRIO", lat = 38.91670317033, lng = -6.07339711488708, 
    portalNumber = "0", stateMsg = "Resultado exacto de la búsqueda", 
    extension = "", state = "1", countryCode = "011"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), `Mayor Nº S.n. Planta 1 Castellon De La Plana/Castello De La Plana` = structure(list(
    id = "2061380170886", province = "Badajoz", comunidadAutonoma = "Extremadura", 
    muni = "Valdetorres", type = "portal", address = "PLAN PARCIAL Nº 1", 
    postalCode = "06474", poblacion = "Valdetorres", geom = "POINT(-6.07339711488708 38.91670317033)", 
    tip_via = "BARRIO", lat = 38.91670317033, lng = -6.07339711488708, 
    portalNumber = "0", stateMsg = "Resultado exacto de la búsqueda", 
    extension = "", state = "1", countryCode = "011"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), `Notario Mas, Plaza Nº 3 Piso 1º Castellon De La Plana` = structure(list(
    id = "120400001216", province = "Castellón/Castelló", comunidadAutonoma = "Comunitat Valenciana", 
    muni = "Castelló de la Plana", type = "portal", address = "NOTARIO MAS", 
    geom = "POINT(-0.0414310339999702 39.9877939630001)", tip_via = "PLAZA", 
    lat = 39.9877939630001, lng = -0.0414310339999702, portalNumber = "5", 
    stateMsg = "Resultado exacto de la búsqueda", state = "1", 
    countryCode = "011"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    `Mayor Nº 56 Piso 1º Castellon De La Plana` = NULL)`
```

My objective is: transforming **geo_info** into a **data frame** while KEEPING the **NULL** rows.

Comment: An answer does not belong in a question post & indication of being answered does not belong in a question post title. Post an answer in an answer post. Accept an answer by clicking on the check mark icon after minimum wait time to show it is the best answer. You can get the raw text of your answer by clicking on 'edited' then cut & paste into an answer. [ask] [answer] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: Please consider posting your answer in an answer post.  You can cut & paste from the raw text by clicking on 'edited' then the 'Source' version that had it (2). PS This post is hard to follow. Also there is no question in it.  [mre] That includes minimal data, don't just use whatever your real data is. It would helps if code that is a table is in columns. PS Please first ask about unexpected output with what you expected & why you expected it justified by documentation. Ask about your overall goal if you are still stuck after you got rid of the bad code misconceptions.